# Get Unique name list from name range

Tags: excel, unique, userform

I have several names in column "H". I want to make a unique name list and show it in the Combobox dropdown list. Here is the code I have but it shows duplicate names in the list.

```
Sub Refresh_Customer_List()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sale_Purchase")

Dim i As Integer

Me.cmb_Cust.Clear
Me.cmb_Cust.AddItem ""
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A")) > 1 Then
For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Me.cmb_Cust.AddItem sh.Range("H" & i).Value
Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Since this is not a free code-writing service, please edit your question to show what you have done so far to try to solve your problem, and where you have run into problems with your attempts. There are many ways of creating unique lists, depending on the Excel version, including worksheet functions, VBA, Power Query

Comment: Here is the Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note how I create the range that might have your dropdown list elements in a few steps in the code below. We define the first row of interest (could be row 2) and then look for the last row with any data `cells(rows.count,col).end(xlup)`

If you have Office 365, you can populate the combolist without using a loop using  something like:

```
Me.cmb_Cust.List = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Range(sh.Cells(2, "A"), sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
```

If you do not have the `Unique` function, there are many VBA objects you can use to obtain a distinct list.  Here is one method using an `ArrayList`, but you can also use a Collection or Dictionary object.

For information on ArrayList, a currently valid link is [VBA ArrayList - A complete guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/)

```
Dim AL As Object, v
Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each v In Range(sh.Cells(1, "A"), sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    If Not AL.contains(v) Then AL.Add (v)
Next v

Me.cmb_Cust.List = AL.toarray
```

Comment: Automation Error

Comment: @InfomediaPlus Ensure the code references the range where your data is stored.

Comment: I'm glad you tried to help me Sir.